# How to get a random number from Google omnibar?

Tags: google-search

Is there any command to get a random number from omnibar?

E.g. like how we can type `21 + 56` and it will show `77`:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

You are now able to type `random number generator` into Google to open an interface where you can generate a number between your desired minimum and maximum:

[image]

---

You can also search for:

- `flip a coin` to roll a 2-sided dice, or;
- `roll a dice` to roll a 6-sided die.

You could also use Google to find a site like [random.org](http://random.org) (which would probably work a lot better), or generate one with the JavaScript 
 Console by entering `Math.ceil(Math.random()*n)` where `n` is the maximum number that you would want to generate.

Answer (score 9):

I can't find anything to suggest that you can do it with Google, but [random.org](http://www.random.org/) has a random number generator on their home page that you can select start and end values and "roll" to get a number between.

They also have coin flippers and other random number related stuff.

Looks like the google calculator [has a lot of features](http://www.googleguide.com/calculator.html) but random numbers is not one of them.

Answer (score 4):

Google does not have a function of random number generation. Instead, you can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com).

For example, [this query](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=randomreal%5B%7B0,1%7D%5D) generates a random real number between 0 and 1. Again, [this query](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=randominteger%5B%7B0,100%7D%5D) generates a random integer number between 0 and 100.

Comment: Is this real random like random.org or pseudorandom (like what Google already has)?

Answer (score 4):

Bookmark the following link. It will generate a random number between `1` and `?` from your browser.

```
javascript:alert%28Math.ceil%28Math.random%28%29*%28prompt%28%271-?%27,%276%27%29*1%29%29%29
```

Comment: This is quite "troublesome" actually....

Answer (score 3):

Google can roll a six-sided die, fyi.

Using Google voice search: "OK Google roll a die"
Using Google search box: "roll a die"

Comment: Are you talking about phones? This doesn't seem to work with google search or omnibar.

Comment: I just typed 'roll a die' into the Chrome omnibox on my Chromebook and it worked for me.

Comment: @pacerier: It may be a regional thing.

Comment: @AlE., Seems that the update has reached here now. Nice, we can "[flip a coin](http://google.com/search?q=flip+a+coin)" too.

Answer (score 2):

Google recognizes the phrase "random number x to y" and returns the expected result. It also provides a little interface to generate more numbers in the same range:

[image: Google Random Numbers]

Comment: This [doesn't work for me](https://i.imgur.com/WTq2UvA.png) in the Chrome **omnibar** though, as the question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

type "generate a random number" in the search bar.

[image: generate a random number with google]